# Trying to use Wildcards in SQLite Browser but its not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, wildcard

i want to display all the names that start with S.
so i tried writing this:

```
select 
     * 
from 
     User 
where 
     name = 'S%';
```

0 rows returned.

Comment: use `name like 'S%'`

Comment: `=` is for *equality* where the thing on the left is *equal* to the thing on the right - none of your values are *equal* to `"S%"`.  Use `LIKE` instead when your using wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
     * 
from 
     User 
where 
     name like 'S%';
```

If you want to read up on how wildcards work: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp